# Ogre3D strange behavior

Tags: c++, ogre3d

I compiled Ogre on my Lubuntu 10.04 with LXDE environment, and when I try to start ./SampleBrowser_d from /bin i have incomplete window...it haven't got background, I can't click on accept and i can't choose OpenGL from avaible list..Anybody know what's it and how fix it ?
Here's some screenshots:
[link text](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/7811/1b4d90397f29.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably not really a stackoverflow question. Troubleshooting applications (or sample apps in your case) isn't really programming related. Try on super user maybe? Or just on Ogre's forum. Or hit the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the same directory as your executable? If not ogre may fail to find "plugins.cfg" and other media and show strange things. This happened to me once, as i called

```
#> /opt/OGRE/samples/SampleBrowser
```

directly instead of

```
#> cd /opt/OGRE/samples/
#> ./SampleBrowser
```